# How to set signtool.exe location in visual studio 2015 community

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, signtool

I've been stuck in this for a couple of hours.
I want to deploy my C# application using a Visual Studio ("Windows") Installer instead of a Click Once Installer.
For doing that, I  had to install an extension called "Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects", which I did.
But once I finally created the setup project for my solution, when I try to build it, I get the following error:

> "Sign tool was not found at path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\signtool.exe"

I checked that in fact, signtool.exe isn't there. But after a little research I found that signtool.exe is located under:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64 and 
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86

No here's is my question: how do I tell Visual Studio where the signtool.exe is located? is it a global, visual studio configuration or a project specific configuration?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variable **WindowsSdkDir**. For example in command line:

```
"%WindowsSdkDir%bin\x64\signtool.exe"
```

or within msbuild script:

```
$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\x64\signtool.exe
```

instead of x64 you can use x86 if you use 32-bit windows version

Comment: It's hard to keep track of environment variables and there are many related answers that perform gymnastics. This is a keeper.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, will be much better to add

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86
```

path to the global system path (via ControlPanel->System->Advanced system settings->Environment variables...

Comment: I just tried that. But my Visual Studio is still looking into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\.
It seems like a project specific issue, since I created a new windows form application and ran it without troubles.

Comment: Could you please share your setup project with me? I've installed "Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects" templates but can't find signature dialog or configuration page...

Comment: Tutorial for what? It has nothing about signtool.exe. As for me, I do have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64 and C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86` on my path, so I don't have any problem with signtool.exe, even from command line or with setup project built from "Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects" template.
JFYI, there is no location for signtool.exe at the setup project file. So, probably you've added incorrect path to system environment, or you just need to restart Visual Studio.